# convert array of objects into object of objects properties from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object

I need to convert an array of objects into an object of objects properties from the array.

Here is an example of an `array of objects`

```
const array = [
 {
  book:5,
  car: 6,
  pc: 7
 },
 {
  headphone: 9,
  keyboard: 10
 },
];
```

I need it to be converted to

```
const obj = {
 book:5,
 car: 6,
 pc: 7,
 headphone: 9,
 keyboard: 10
};
```

I tried many ways but can't achieve the final result. Thanks in advance

Comment: These type of questions attract people that almost code golf the answer without giving you any explanation on what they did. Granted, you'll be back in 2 days with a new request.

Comment: `const obj = Object.assign({}, ...array)` is likely the cleanest. The spread operator will do the job here, and Object.assign does exactly what you need.

Comment: @nicholaswmin as you can see, 2 years already passed, and you can see that I'm not back with another request related to this, so stop making wrong assumptions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could spread the array as parameters ([spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) for [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), which returns a single object.

```js
const
    array = [{ book: 5, car: 6, pc: 7 }, { headphone: 9, keyboard: 10 }],
    object = Object.assign({}, ...array);
    
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.reduce()` and `Object.assign()` methods:

```js
const array = [
  {book:5, car: 6, pc: 7},
  {headphone: 9, keyboard: 10},
];

const result = array.reduce((r, c) => Object.assign(r, c), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks this worked, but I will accept @Nina Scholz answer, because it has less code

Answer (score 0):

You can also loop through the array using for loops. Using .reduce() and Object.assign() may not me that clear to understang what is happening for people that don't understand too much about Objects in js, but is definitively less code.

```
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    for (let key in array[i]) {
        if (array[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            obj[key] = array[i][key];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
let obj = {}

for(let object of array) {
  Object.assign(obj, object)
}

console.log(obj)
```