# How can I do Javascript / Jquery create increase-able multi dimenssional object with multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to build a increase-able data upload document,

currently the HTML like this

```js
function getData() {
  let newArr = [];
  var room = {};
  var time = {};
  var prod = {};
  var quan = {};

  var room = $('.room').each(function() {
    room.push($(this).val());
  });
  var time = $('.time').each(function() {
    time.push($(this).val());
  });
  var prod = $('.prod').each(function() {
    prod.push($(this).val());
  });
  var quan = $('.quan').each(function() {
    quan.push($(this).val());
  });

  newArr.push({
    room,
    time,
    prod,
    quan,
  });
  console.log(newArr)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="insert">
  <input type="text" name="room[]" class="room">
  <input type="text" name="time[]" class="time">
  <input type="text" name="prod[]" class="prod">
  <input type="text" name="quan[]" class="quan">
</div>
<div class="insert">
  <input type="text" name="room[]" class="room">
  <input type="text" name="time[]" class="time">
  <input type="text" name="prod[]" class="prod">
  <input type="text" name="quan[]" class="quan">
</div>
<div>
  <button name="btnSubmit" onclick="getData()">Click</button>
</div>
```

hope to get date kind of the following structure

```
Array 
[
  Object1 => {
    "room":"string/number", "time":"string/number", "prod":"string/number", "quan":"string/number"
  }
  Object2 => {
    "room":"string/number", "time":"string/number", "prod":"string/number", "quan":"string/number"
  }
]
```

then the error tells me either can not user `.push()` on object,

or it just keep getting `undefined`;

after I check some articles but seems the solution as set up `formData()`

[JavaScript loop over input creates an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48295052/16631494)

which I already had a `formData()` and contains file need to upload.

or some of them would be using `.map()` function alter into another array.

which makes me trying to merge multiple array into one or like below solutions,

now I'm figuring those answers but not very match yet

[combine multiple array elements into single object in javascript1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56713788/16631494)

[convert array of objects into object of objects properties from array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52840144/16631494)

at this current point, hope someone could've help me.

---

for the **increase-able** explain :

after few change now use jQuery prepend/append an object, the second form has been changed to table, first form stays as file-upload.

```
$('#theTable').prepend(`
<tr class="insert">
  <td><input type="text" name="room[]" class="room"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="time[]" class="room"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="prod[]" class="room"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="quan[]" class="room"></td>
</tr>
`);
```

Native javascript (which not using but work)

```
function addInputField() {
  // table
  const table = document.getElementById('theTable');
  // row
  let newRow = table.insertRow(-1);
  newRow.innerHTML += `
    <td><input type="text" name="room[]" class="room"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="time[]" class="time"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="prod[]" class="prod"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="quan[]" class="quan"></td>
    `;
  newRow.className = 'insert';
  table.prepend(newRow);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because you're trying to `push` a value to an object. `push` is for pushing values to arrays not objects.

Try this

```js
function getData() {
    let newArr = [];
    $('.insert').each(function(){
        newArr.push({
            room: $(this).find('[name="room[]"]').val(),
            time: $(this).find('[name="time[]"]').val(),
            prod: $(this).find('[name="prod[]"]').val(),
            quan: $(this).find('[name="quan[]"]').val(),
        })
    })
    
    console.log(newArr)
    return newArr
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="insert">
    <input type="text" name="room[]" class="room">
    <input type="text" name="time[]" class="time">
    <input type="text" name="prod[]" class="prod">
    <input type="text" name="quan[]" class="quan">
</div>
<div class="insert">
    <input type="text" name="room[]" class="room">
    <input type="text" name="time[]" class="time">
    <input type="text" name="prod[]" class="prod">
    <input type="text" name="quan[]" class="quan">
</div>
<div>
    <button name="btnSubmit" onclick="getData()">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is **great** ! I was testing above codes, even combine with other rules, the result still MAKE MY DAY ! LOL
Thank you !